# FLUTTER ERROR :Error: ADB exited with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, exception, build

I am getting this error while running my flutter app.The app launches on chrome but wont launch on the emulator or on a real mobile device

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install 
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\OWASLO\care_giver_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: 
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during 
installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1352177004.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #53): 
com.owaslo.sukithasagayo.caregiver.MainActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) 
requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters 
are present]
Error launching application on Pixel 6.
```

Below is my AndroidManifest file.Ive enabled multidex as well in the gradle file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.owaslo.sukithasagayo.caregiver">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application
    android:label="Sukitha Sagayo Member"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
   <provider
       android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
   </provider>

   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
       
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

below link contains my gradle file
[gradle file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dhrbu6LMie02R9FPh747iOWS3m0w0r_8ZyL8LB5tyQ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Please help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this  property to `<activity>`  as from `android 12` its required to be write this for activity and your device has android api level `31`  which is android - 12

```
android:exported="true"
```

Comment: please in which file should add this property

Comment: Inside android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Enable not only 'USB debugging' but also 'Install via USB' (Xiaomi).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33107746)

Answer (score -2):

What I did was I changed `minSdkversion` in `local.properties` to 29 since my device is an android 10 device, so edit that line depending on your android version and it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)